# User redirect with POST in iframe

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, post, iframe

I am building one of my first MVC 4 applications and I need some help with redirecting users.

I have a windows form application where I use a `AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser` to redirect the user to a specific URL , a SOAP web service to be precise, aswell as sending HTTP POST and HEADER data aswell. 
This is done like so:

```
oHeaders = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + "\n" + "\r";
sPostData = "ExchangeSessionID=" + SessionID;
oPostData = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sPostData);

axWebBrowser2.Navigate2(ref oURL, ref o, ref o, ref oPostData, ref oHeaders);
```

I am looking to replicate this functionality in my MVC application, but am unsure of the how this can be done.

I was hoping to have this within an iframe, but can't find a way of sending the POST and HEADER data from this. This is what I have been trying so far:

**Controller**

```
 ViewBag.URL = TempData["URL"];
 ViewBag.SessionID = TempData["SessionID"];
 ViewBag.FullURL = TempData["URL"] + "?ExchangeSessionID=" + TempData["SessionID"];
 return View();
```

**View**

```
<iframe src="@ViewBag.FullURL" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

Basically I was trying to append the data to the end of the URL hoping this would work for the HTTP POST part. This is what I ended up with:

```
https://www.myurl.aspx?ExchangeSessionID=87689797
```

The user is being directed to the page, but the web service is giving me an error ( which tells me it is now receiving the POST data).

Can some please help me to try and fix this, or even give me advice on how to go about this another way. Like I said, I'm fairly new to MVC applications and I'm not entirely sure what I'm tryin to do is even possible.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided to answer this question myself incase anybody is looking to do something similar in the future.

The first step was to create my iframe:

```
<iframe name="myframe" src="" width="100%" height="700px"></iframe>
```

Next I want to create a form with a button which, when pressed, will post the data to the url while targeting the iFrame (Note the target attribute of the form):

```
<form action="@ViewBag.URL" method="post" target="myframe">
    <input type="hidden" name="ExchangeSessionID" value="@ViewBag.SessionID" />        
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

So what happens is, when the button is pressed, the form posts the ExchangeSessionID to the target URL and then the page response is displayed inside the iFrame.